# Porque mi ajax no detecta informacion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo este problema, estoy haciendo un login y un register pero cuando intento verificar si los datos se estan enviando por medio de un `alert();` no se esta mandando la infomacion.

Codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>RegisterPrueba</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="guardar" method="POST">

    <input type="text" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" id="Guardar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Guardar').click(function() {
      var datos = $('#guardar').serialize();

      alert(datos);
      return false;

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "guardar.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function() {


        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: noto que en tu js asignas a la variable datos lo que llega por el id guardar pero al momento de ver tu form en vez de decir id, dice class

Comment: @Alfredo ya lo cambie y nada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte del problema con el ID que te indican otros usuarios, el método [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) toma los valores de los campos usando su `name`. Tus campos no tienen atributo `name`. Añádeselo y ya te funcionará (también tendrás que añadir el id al formulario):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>RegisterPrueba</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="guardar" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" id="Guardar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Guardar').click(function() {
      var datos = $('#guardar').serialize();

      alert(datos);
      return false;

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "guardar.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function() {


        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaría poner este código en el evento submit del form

```
$('#guardarForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var datos= $('#guardarForm').serialize();
      alert(datos);
      return false;

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "guardar.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function() {


        }
      });
});
```

Comment: ya lo coloque id y sigue igual xD

Comment: Perdon, alli actualice

Comment: no funciona :cc

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos HTML o lo mismo las etiquetas puedes accederlas por medio de JS a través de su id o class; del modo siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In repellat, earum, voluptates officiis tempora laudantium blanditiis magnam mollitia cumque ipsam eos perferendis numquam. Est adipisci officia, quas vel recusandae quibusdam.</p>
<span class="clase">hola</span>

<script>
    let parrafo = document.querySelector("#parrafo")
    let span = document.querySelector(".clase")

    parrafo.style.color = "red"

    span.style.color = "orange"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Es decir:

> 1. con el símbolo de # es para los id
> 2. con el símbolo de . es para las class

Para tu ejercicio, yo cambiaría la class por un id, de tal modo que tu ejercicio quede así

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RegisterPrueba</title>


        <script src="JS/Jquery 3.3.1.js" ></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="guardarDatos" method="POST">

            <input type="text" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <input type="submit" id="Guardar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Guardar').click(function(){
            var datos= $('#guardarDatos').serialize();

            alert(datos);
            return false;

            $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                url:"guardar.php",
                data: datos,
                success:function(){


                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```